# HTTPD port 80 not working after install apache tomcat

Tags: centos, java, httpd, apache2, tomcat9

I am using AWS EC2 and Centos.

Before I installed apache tomacat 9, I still able to access my website in port 80, or at least I can access my ip address in browser with welcome page. But after installing apache tomcat, all my virtual host in port 80 is going to apache tomcat page.

Here is the network status

[image]

And when I open the **localhost_access_log.2020-04-28.txt** under my tomcat directory, I can see that all accesses to my website which should be in port 80 are shown in that log, as shown in the image bellow

[image]

Here is the server.xml in the tomcat

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
                                                                                                                                                                            <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->                                                                                                                      
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

By the configuration above, tomcat should go to port 8080. But the fact is that all my virtual host (port 80) is redirected to apache tomcat page.

Can please help me what is wrong here. I do really need to fix it asap, tried to fix it from yesterday but seems like the only way is asking it here.

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Apache configs. You can found it in folder /etc/httpd 
I would suggest that a redirect to the tomcat was added to the apache's config.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. I check my apache config and it says `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`, there is nothing wrong there